# String Stream & cli

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments, stringstream

I have this program and I want to fill the tables array with the values passed from the command line in integer form . However It string s is only being assigned argument 6 .. what is the problem ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <locale>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
int i;
int tables[100];
stringstream str;
string s;
int result;
char value;

if(argc <=1){
 cout<<"NO ARGUMENTS PASSED"<<endl;
 exit(0);
}

/*char value = *argv[1];
cout<<value<<endl;
str << value;
str >> s;
result = stoi(s,nullptr,10);
cout<<result<<endl;*/

for (i=1;i<argc;i++){
 if(isdigit(*argv[i])){
  value = *argv[i];
  str<<value;
  str>>s;
  cout<<s<<endl;
  tables[i-1] = stoi(s,nullptr,10);

}

}



}
```

Comment: You need to learn to use a debugger.  See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: What do you mean by "s is only being assigned argument 6".  How many arguments are you passing?

Comment: if i pas 5 6 7 8 .. s is being assigned only 6 and hence the tables array contains only 6 4 times

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `stringstream` in the wrong way.

By writing `str >> s` you are reaching `eof` in the stream.
To fix this, you can avoid to use `stringstream` and instead directly assign `value` to `s`.
If you want to use `stringstream`, you can reset it back to initial state after writing to `s` as follows:

```
str.str(std::string{});
str.clear();
```

and use it again

Answer (score 0):

isdigit function test if a char is a digit, so the command line

```
isdigit(*argv[i])
```

Return true is the firts character of the char* is a digit. What you want is to convert a char* to an integer, I suggest to take a look at the [atoi function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/).

However, the string convertion for printing your result is not necessary.